# How do I mock out authentication for functional tests in applications using Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, functional-testing

I have a suite of Selenium-driven functional tests for a web application I'm developing. I've recently integrated with Spring Security as a means of handling authentication. All of my functional tests now fail, naturally, given that every request is now taken to a login screen rather than the page that was originally requested.

There are many ways I can go about tackling this problem, of course, but none of them seem particularly appealing. Hard coding in dummy credentials into my testing code and then logging in as part of every test case seems ugly, fragile, and insecure. Adding in some kind of application level switch to disable authentication for test purposes likewise seems like a bad idea- any chance that security could be disabled in production is undesirable.

Surely I am not the first person to encounter this issue. What is the best means of handling authentication when writing functional tests for an application using Spring Security?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a Spring Security issue, this would be the case with any system that required logins to access certain pages.   Personally I would choose the dummy credentials route.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same situation... I resolved time before adding this to each test (you must login first and copy the sessionId - only for an already running site): def setup() {
  browser.augmentedDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  browser.augmentedDriver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("PHPSESSID", "yourSessionID"))
  browser.config.autoClearCookies = false
 }